# ErrorObjectNotFound javascript error on upload csv

Tags: lightning, javascript, error, aura, fileupload

I was working on a feature to load records as picklist values on to a custom lookup component  from a csv upload. The functionality was working as expected, but I get an error that says "ErrorObjectNotFound" javascript error (I will screenshot the error if necessary).

So I tried many solutions in order to find any error. Two things I noticed, 1 being a solution:

1. I get different errors in chrome than in mozilla firefox; Although chrome is the browser where I do all the testing.
2. On adding setTimeOut to my uploader function in the controller by 1ms,  the JS issue gets resolved. I used setTimeOut hoping that the ongoing upload is messing with the current transaction with the custom lookup.

I don't know why it worked and so posted the problem here to see if there is an explanation!

My Question is: What is source of this issue (error attached below).

[image]

Comment: Please add a *question* and a verbatim error message.

Comment: Will correct the post. Got carried away. Thanks!